# How to add and open html file in non webapp maven project

Tags: java, html, bundle

I created a maven project which is bundle in Apache ServiceMix now.

Now i want to add html file to this project and print somethink on it.

[image]

How to do it? I try do this but when i want to open index.html i got an error:

```
URI u = new URI("/MyCommands/src/main/webapp/index.html");
```

Couldn't find file - in karaf console.

i tried `URI u = new URI("index.html");` to, but it didnt work.

Please help me :(

Error log

[image]

Comment: I think this answer it all: `Couldn't find file`. Have you deal with that? Where is your file located?

Comment: You have it on picture: src/main/webapp

Comment: I add this index.html to each folder and I still cant open it ;(

Answer (score 1):

Ok I guess you only need to specify the path correctly and judging from your project structure you need:

```
URI u = new URI("src/main/webapp/index.html");
```

The path `/MyCommands/src/main/webapp/index.html` that gives you the error signifies an absolute path in your machine. Does this correspond to your actual folder structure?

If you wanted a relative path (beginning from your source root folder you should not use the first forward slash `/`, something like `MyCommands/src/main/webapp/index.html` but in your case I think `MyCommands/` is unnecessary.

Edit:

Copying from the `Class Desktop` [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#browse%28java.net.URI%29) for `browse()` method :

> IOException - if the user default browser is not found, or it fails to
>   be launched, or the default handler application failed to be launched

Judging from the above maybe you should check if your browser has some problem launching.
Can you open anyother URI instead of the one specified for example?

Comment: java.io.IOException: Failed to open src/main/webapp/index.html.

Remember that is not webapp application, but quickstart.

I have no idea too why this dont work.

Comment: What is the exact exception message you get?

Comment: java.io.IOException: Failed to open src/main/webapp/index.html
Can not find the file specified/

Comment: So you can see the actual file in `src/main/webapp` folder and despite that you get this error?

Comment: I cant open this file just in a code when i 
URI u = new URI("MyCommands/src/main/webapp/index.html");
java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop().browse(u);
I cant open this file regardless of location in project.